# In what media has the electric charge of an electron been measured?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, charge

I need specific references of experiments that have measured the electric charge of an electron in different media (water, air, others). I have found some performed in air or vacuum (Millikan, Thomson, etc) but none in water or other denser medium.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that the charge on the electron depends on the media it is in?

Comment: Well @JonCuster one could mathematically build up a theory , where the charge of the electron changes in a medium and the dialetric constant remains the same.

Comment: @Cerise - one can build many theories. Only a few of them are useful. For tuneable dielectrics, it is much easier to consider that changing atom positions in the crystal (with constant electron charge) changes the dielectric rather than somehow the charge on the electron changes resulting in shifting atom positions. That is even before one considers totally rewriting the Standard Model for particle physics.

Comment: @JonCuster in fact we assume some independencies(value of charge in a medium) based on human logic.But in the end it is nothing more than human logic so who knows.Maybe a subatomic particle can have different quantum numbers in different circumstances.

Comment: @Cerise - and maybe invisible unicorns are responsible for the universe.

Comment: @JonCuster Have you ruled it out?

Comment: As a useful scientific theory, yes.

Comment: Somebody voted to close because it's not mainstream physics? How is experimental testing of the assumptions behind the math not mainstream physics?

Comment: @JonCuster I have a reason to believe that the charge of the electron might be altered somehow by the media, and it surprises me that the charge of the electron is assumed to be invariant without any experiment in different media supporting it. Probably I am wrong, but that is why I ask the question, to confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to measure the electron's charge these days is by [observing shot noise](https://physicsopenlab.org/2016/10/10/shot-noise-and-electron-charge/). The apparatus measures the current fluctuations in a semiconductor diode. Various conductive, semiconductive, resistive, and insulating "media" are involved, but neither vacuum nor air are important components of the apparatus.

Comment: "...but neither vacuum nor air are important components of the apparatus."Maybe they are!Who knows?Who cares?+1

Comment: @JonDoty thanks! I have gone through your referred paper, and if I am not mistaken they get a measure slightly different than the conventional "measured/invariable" one... and I do not find the results for different measures in different media

Comment: @JuanMoreno Every measurement gets a slightly different answer due to experimental error. A careful experiment would include an error analysis. The main virtue of the shot noise technique is not its accuracy but its accessibility: you can pretty easily do this at home.